# Excel: Attempting to have 2 tables of different size communicate without a #SPILL error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables, spill-range

I run into the error because I am trying to make a string of formulas that read when between 2 dates in "table 1" is negative it pulls information from "table 2" to have it highlighted on the graph as a data callout.  Biggest problem I'm having is since its attempting to read from 2 different sized arrays it outputs a #SPILL error.  I would like to have "table 1" read the outputs from "table 2" and exclude Cells if it has already called it out before.  The Index-Match function is the closest I've come but it only relays 1 cell of information and fails to update as the information is added into either "table 1" or "table 2".

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

[image: Graph]

I do apologize if I didn't explain this well enough but any help is appreciated.

Match-Index function worked well but failed to update as a more information was added into the tables

Is there any way to have excel exclude cells that were already called out?

Comment: It's difficult to follow what exactly you are after. Could you include an example?

Comment: Hello,
I attached 3 pictures of my sheet that hopefully help a bit. The main code in (Delay Explanation) is =IF([@Delta]<0,Delays[Reason],"")

Comment: Please add the formula to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Delays[Reason]` wants to return three rows - but there is not enough space to spill down - because next cell is blocked by the next formula. Therefore you receive the error.

You have to retrieve the delays reason for the special date.

As I don't know if there could be overalpping events for delays I added the `TEXTJOIN` function to merge two or more reasons into one cell.

```
=IF([@delta]<0,
        TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,
                  FILTER(Delays[reason],([@date]>=Delays[delay began])*([@date]<=Delays[delay ended]),"- no reason found")
        ),"")
```